# .Net core 3.1 custom authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core

I writing a .Net core API and my API itself does not have any authentication or authorization logic. The authentication and authorization are handled by a separate system so in order to secure my endpoints I need to forward each incoming request to the external system and decide if the user is authenticated depending upon the value being returned from the external system.

I want to know whats the best approach to implement something like this, as I think it can be done with a `CustomAuthorize` attribute or `middleware` or by adding a `CustomAuthPolicy`. There are many bits and pieces in Auth with .Net core, I would really appreciate if someone can guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution that I am currently using:

This solution works great, and if you have the following in a referenced project, it can easily be reused.

Create a Custom Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyAuthAttr : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    //Add Auth logic here using HttpClient or whatever you use to authenticate.
    //You can access your headers through actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers


    //When completed with your logic, you can continue your controller execution
    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
}
```

This attribute can be applied to your controllers like this:

```
[MyAuthAttr]
public class MySecureControllerController {...}
```

This can be applied to the Controller's class as global auth, or any of the endpoints within the controller as specific auth.

So this will work too:

```
[Route("Do")]
[MyAuthAttr]
public IActionResult DoThaThing(Foo foo) {...}
```

Comment: Another cool thing about this, you can add properties to the attribute to allow for anonymous auth or things like that.

You can also use the same pattern to create attributes to validate other things like permissions etc.